# What ELSE can cause Apache to display a CGI instead of it's output?

Tags: apache, configuration, webserver, cgi

I have a newly configured Apache 2.4.7 webserver (AIX7 ).  It is displaying the contents of my CGIs instead of their output.

I have this in my conf file:

```
LoadModule cgi_module /opt/freeware/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_cgi.so

AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin      "/var/www/cgi-bin"
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    Options +FollowSymLinks +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My CGIs behave as expected if run from the CLI.  They are world-readable and world-executable. The shebang line is correct. There are no relevant messages in error_log.

What ELSE can cause the server to not execute a CGI?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.  I had two different conf directories.  Apache was looking at a configuration in a different location which had the default values.

Lesson learned: If Apache seems to be ignoring your config file, make sure you're looking at the right file.